# Identical class name in different files phpunit conflict

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

When i test my application on Zend Framework 2 i have strange error. For example, i have 2 phpunit test files:

1:

```
namespace Test\Model;

class Test1Test extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function test1test() {
        $this->assertTrue((new \Austero\Model\Test1())->t1());
    }
}
```

2:

```
namespace Test\Model;

class Test2Test extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function test1test() {
        $this->assertTrue((new \Austero\Model\Test2())->t2());
    }
}
```

And 2 tested model files:

```
namespace App\Model;

class Test1 {

    public function t1() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And:

```
namespace App\Model;

use
    \App\Controller\Test1; // THERE USE FILE FROM ANOTHER NAMESPACE WITH SAME NAME THAT Test1 FROM App\Model NAMESPACE

class Test2 {

    public function t2() {
        (new Test1())->t3();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then i got:
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use App\Controller\Test1 as Test1 because the name is already in use in /home/user/projects/app/module/App/src/App/Model/Test2.php on line 5

How can i avoid this, without change used alias? Thanks for answer

Comment: Try `use \App\Controller\Test1 as ControllerTest1;` and change `new Test1()` to `new ControllerTest1`

Comment: It works well, but i cant change all project for one test :( thx for advice anyway

Comment: Well I don't think there is other way around it since you have overlap of names. Basically when you say `use` you include the name of the namespace inside do any class repetition like this would cause problems. The problem is with the naming, try to refactor. You other option is to not include `use` and write the whole namespace instead like this `new \App\Controller\Test1()`

Comment: @ziGi is correct, this is the way PHP namespaces work and the only ways to avoid it are the ones listed (alias the import or reference the class by it's fully-qualified class name)